# Syntax choice for type parameter variance in C# and VB

Tags: vb.net, c#-4.0, syntax, language-design, language-features

In both C# and VB, type parameter modifiers are used to express the variance of type parameters. For example, the C# version looks like:

```
interface Foo<in X, out Y> { }
```

and the VB version looks like:

```
Interface Foo(Of In X, Out Y)

End Interface
```

Since variance specifications basically restrict where and how a type parameter can be used, I tend to think of them as additional constraints on type parameters.

I'm just curious as to why they aren't represented so. I mean, why are they represented in both languages as additional modifiers on type parameters, instead of being added to the type constraint list? If they were type constraints, the C# version would've looked like:

```
interface Foo<X, Y> where X:in where Y:out { }
```

and the VB version would've looked like:

```
Interface Foo(Of X As In, Y As Out)

End Interface
```

So, does anyone know if there was some reasoning behind the particular syntax choice for expressing type parameter variance in these languages, or was it just random?

Comment: Yeah. I agree that the current implementation looks cleaner, and I don't have any issues with that.
But if these are just additional constraints, it wouldn't make sense to give them a special place, unless they're used frequently. While type parameter variance is a really nice feature, I can't imagine using it frequently enough to warrant a specialized syntax.
So, I was just wondering if I'm wrong to be treating them as type parameter constraints.

Comment: They aren't type parameter contraints, at all, though... You shoudln't think of these as constraints on the type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the language designers made a good choice here.

The reason for this is that covariance and contravariance are not constraints on the type (X/Y in your case), but rather on the interface itself.

If you used the `where X: in` or `Of X As In` syntax, you're suggesting a constraint on **the type X**.  However, covariance and contravariance are really "constraints" on the interface itself - how the generic type of interface is going to use the type "T".  For example, by saying:

```
interface Foo<out X> {}
```

You're saying "This interface only uses **X** as an output", which really is saying that you're constraining **your** *usage of X* in a way that allows covariance.

This is very different than saying "X needs to be constrainted to a specific type", since this isn't a constraint on X.

By introducing a new syntax, the language designers have allowed us to conceptualize this more effectively by not mixing messages.

Comment: Ah! That makes a lot of sense. Never looked at it that way.

And I couldn't agree more about this syntax choice being a good one, now that I understand that type parameter variance specs aren't just constraints.

Thanks for the explanation :)

Comment: @CodeMangler: Glad that helped.  Covariance and contravariance are kind of tricky to wrap your head around - but yes, you definitely shouldn't think of these as constraints on the type - they really aren't constraining the type at all. :)